# "To" as "compared to"

Tags: word-usage, ellipsis, parsing

> On Monday, January 28, Grandview played at Inglis but notched only five goals **to seven for Inglis**. ([source](https://grandviewexponent.newspaperarchive.com/grandview-exponent/1963-01-24/))
>
> So often he has played second fiddle to Wright and notched only nine goals last season **to his partner's 30**. ([source](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/play-second-fiddle-to-somebody))

These sentences read a little odd to me. The meaning is clear, but can "to" **commonly** stand in for "compared to"? If this indeed is a common usage, some other example sentences would be helpful. Or are these sentences uncommon instances of ellipsis? Also, what is the function of the boldfaced parts? Adverbial complement?

Comment: I believe this is idiomatic British English, but it's intelligible to others.   I've usually heard it in sports writing / broadcasts, and not so often elsewhere.

Comment: @BadZen That makes sense. I am just starting to pick up some idiosyncrasies in sports writing. For the most part, it still grates.

Comment: An American might say "On Monday the 28th, Inglis beat Grandview at home five to seven."  and "He's really been the second man behind Wright, scoring just nine goals last season versus Wright's thirty."